Sometimes the keyboard is turned off when waking from standby after upgrading to Debian12
After upgrading to Debian12 with KDE, sometimes the keyboard of a laptop is turned off while the touchpad still works. It doesn't work again after putting it back into standby and then waking it from standby. It really is in standby as one could hear if it wasn't.
After waking from Hibernate or when just locking the screen the keyboard does work.
Moreover, often if not always under some conditions (which I'll try to find out and then add) the laptop shows the prior screen for 0.2-4.0 seconds before it shows the lockscreen. This obviously is a privacy issue and could be linked to the prior problem.
When I just Log Out the keyboard works fine at the lockscreen. It only doesn't work when resuming from sleep (opening the lid after it was closed or pressing the power button after clicking Sleep).
Why does this occur and how to prevent it?

Details:
I don't know if the latter problem only appeared after the upgrade but I'm fairly sure the former only appeared directly or some time after upgrading to Debian12. This only occurred sometimes earlier but now occurs every time I wake from standby which probably means it occurs more likely when waking it up right after putting it to standby since I've been doing that when testing.
It occurs with X11 and with Wayland. I previously had set it to auto-login with session "Plasma (X11)" in KDE's Login Screen (SDDM) configs and after the upgrade it apparently was changed to "Kodi" while loginctl show-session 1 -p Type still just showed X11. I changed it to "Plasma (Wayland)" and the problem persists. In the bottom left it says "Virtual Keyboard" (this could be relevant) and when I click on it nothing happens. sudo swapon --show shows that a swap partition is used. Just recently they keyboard usually worked when waking from standby, now it doesn't seem to work anymore even when not immediately resuming from sleep. It also happened twice that it shut down when closing the Lid with the lockscreen open where the keyboard is working (that occurs when it auto-locks the screen due to inactivity).
These are some log entries at the time found manually with sudo journalctl --since today | tail -n 3000:
Right after Lid closed.:
kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting methd \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous errors (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20220331/psparse-529)
kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
systemd-logind: The system will suspend now!
[...]
systemd-sleep: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...

After this entry there are no entries before -- Boot {uid} -- even though I woke the computer up from sleep and pressed login twice to make it show twice.
Secure boot is enabled. Disabling secure boot didn't solve the problem but enables a function to Hibernate next to Sleep. When putting it to hibernation it shuts down, a second afterwards turns on again and after another second actually shuts down. When waking from hibernation, the keyboard does work. I do not want to use that for the two reasons that I'd like to have Secure Boot enabled and because that requires a longer startup where also the disk password needs to be entered another time. When configuring under KDE'S Energy Saving that closing the laptop lid makes it go to "Hybrid Sleep", the keyboard also doesn't work after waking from it. When clicking "Hibernate" from this lockscreen where it doesn't work and then waking from it, the keyboard does work. As a workaround for now I'm configuring it to go Hibernate but I'm clueless as to why waking from Sleep stopped working.
Apparently, the logs vary a lot per try and after another try I found kscreenlocker_greet: pam_unix(kde:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=1000 euid=1000 tty= ruser= rhost=  user{username} a short time after kernel: ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3 but nothing about the keyboard except:
ksmserver:kf.kirigami: Failed to find a Kirigami platform plugin
ksmserver: file:///usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components/VirtualKeyboard.qml:12:1. Type InputPanel unavailable
ksmserver: qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/InputPanel.qml:138:5: Type Keyboard unavailable
ksmserver: qrc:/QtQuick/VirtualKeyboard/content/components/Keyboard.qml:38:1: module "QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Plugins" is not installed
systemd: Reached target sleep.target - Sleep.

Unlike another machine where this problem doesn't occur, I have libqt5virtualkeyboard5 and qml-module-qtquick-virtualkeyboard installed. Uninstalling those two (which doesn't ask for also removing anything else) didn't solve the problem. qtvirtualkeyboard5-doc and keyboard-configuration are installed on both Deb12 machines. At another try there is kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep) after systemd-sleep: Entering sleep state 'suspend'... but nothing afterward even though I was waking it up from suspend and trying to use the keyboard until the -- Boot entry.
At another try the last log entry before suspend was kernel: (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s while the first after was kernel: (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq (note I only have some wifi firmware and intel-microcode installed from non-free) and other pre-suspend entries like kernel: ata1.00: Entering standby power mode kernel: psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on making it seem like the device does not go into actual sleep.
I think this is a problem of the timestamps or the log where logentries are written after resuming from standby. Until today, resuming from sleep worked more than half of the time so I hope that it never works now has to do with resuming from standby immediately after. Another strange thing is that in the journalctl logs where only is one entry kscreenlocker_greet[3242]: pam_unix(kde:auth): authentication failure;[...] at the minute that I deliberately clicked the login button four times in a row so that it showed "Unlocking failed" four times on the loginscreen. Directly after this authentication failure message there is:
 sddm[1175]: Adding new display on vt 8 ...
 sddm[1175]: Loading theme configuration from ""
 sddm[1175]: Display server starting...
 sddm[1175]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{[id1]}"
 sddm[1175]: Running: /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{id1]} -background none -noreset -displayfd 21 -seat seat0 vt8
 kernel: Lockdown: Xorg: raw io port access is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
 sddm[1175]: Setting default cursor
 sddm[1175]: Running display setup script  "/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup"
 sddm[1175]: Display server started.
 sddm[1175]: Socket server starting...
 sddm[1175]: Socket server started.
 sddm[1175]: Loading theme configuration from "/usr/share/sddm/themes/debian-maui/theme.conf"
 sddm[1175]: Greeter starting...
 sddm[1175]: Adding cookie to "/var/run/sddm/{id1]}"
 sddm-helper[3739]: [PAM] Starting...
 sddm-helper[3739]: [PAM] Authenticating...
 sddm-helper[3739]: [PAM] returning.
 sddm-helper[3739]: pam_unix(sddm-greeter:session): session opened for user sddm(uid=112) by (uid=0)

Something is definitely very wrong but some help would be good so that I can at least file a useful bug report at the appropriate place/package if this is not already a known issue. Right now, suspend can't be used anymore.
Update: After the keyboard never worked after resuming from Sleep for at least 10 different kinds tries, now clicking Sleep in the bottom left caused a shutdown again, afterwards the keyboard works again when resuming from sleep but I think it's only back to sometimes being dysfunctional. Issue now is here.

Sometimes it's the whole display rather than the keyboard that can freeze, except for the mouse pointer. Can you log from remote (ssh) become root and switch to a console using chvt? You should try it when it works (to verify it can switch) and when the keyboard fails (to verify it's really a keyboard problem and not a display problem).

I don't think there are display issues. I can do everything one can do with the mouse there such as switching user, pressing the shutdown button, focusing the password box, and so on. When I click on the password box, enter my password, press enter, it doesn't log me in. It could be that I had such a display issue before but there I could always log in by just entering. I don't use SSH and don't think I have it allowed in nftables. Should I test with an USB keyboard? Note that I currently have an issue at another computer with that kb where its lights turn on min after putting the PC sleep

Fine, I had to ask. But to troubleshoot you need remote access one way or an other, even if "remote" works with an external USB keyboard. I have no idea about the problem, but I'd think that without keyboard it becomes difficult to debug.

When I connect an external USB keyboard I can enter text just fine. This problem occurs even when I only boot up the PC let it load everything and then put it to standby. Maybe there is something somewhere in some logs and maybe it has sth to do with new hibernation or secure boot features.
